# How to bring SQL Variable into GUI?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to insert in my GUI the variable `anzahl` from the minor class in a text field. Counting works in the minor class, but I do not know how I now get the counted value in the GUI? In the GUI, I just want to see the value from the minor class. Can someone help me with the code examples?

Minor Class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Count {

    static Connection conn;
    static Statement eintrag;
    static Statement eintrag2;
    static JLabel textPB1;
    static String ausgabe;
    public static String anzahl;
    Statement abfrage;
    int i;
    ResultSet res;
    private int num;

    Count() {

        try {

              Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

                    Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://fm-s012mp.fhws.de","Java","xyc");

                    Statement s = con.createStatement();

                    ResultSet res;

                    res = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) AS anzahl FROM `lagersystem_test`.`00_hauptdatenbank` WHERE Boxinhalt > '0'" );

                    while (res.next() ) {

                          System.out.print(res.getString("anzahl") );


                          GUI_Lager.setTextExternally(res.getString("anzahl")); 
                                 }

                    res.close();
                    s.close();
                    con.close();

              }

              catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(""+e.getMessage());}
           }

        }
```

GUI: (short Form)

```
public class GUI_Lager extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  JLabel textPB; // "Text Prozessbar
    static JLabel textPB1;
    (....)

  public GUI_Lager() {

  textPB1 = new JLabel(""); // Variable from the Class
        textPB1.setBounds(200, 10, 400, 25);
        textPB1.setVisible(true);
        add(textPB1);

  (....)

   }

    public static void setTextExternally(String text) {
            textPB1.setText(text);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}

}
```

Comment: @FHWS...not sure if you've checked back to this question, but did my solution not work for you? Let me know if you need a different idea worked out.

Answer (score 0):

To update a JLabel, you would use:

```
yourLabel.setText("your text");
```

So in context with the code provided in your question (assuming it is working without issue), you would do this:

```
while (res.next() == true) {

    //System.out.print(res.getString("anzahl") );
    //This "anzahl" i want to have in my GUI  

    textPB1.setText(res.getString("anzahl"));   //Now you should have the label set

}
```

If for some reason the JLabel does not like being changed that way in a loop, you could also just instantiate a new object reference like so:

```
textPB1 = new JLabel(res.getString("anzahl"));
```

**Update 1:**

If you need to set the value from a different class simply create a method in the class with textPB1, which you will call from the class you are grabbing the DB value from, like so:

```
public static void setTextExternally(String text){
    textPB1.setText(text);
    //or
    textPB1 = new JLabel(text);
}
```

Then in your loop from before, do this:

```
while (res.next() == true) {

   //label should be set in other class using setter method below
    MainGUI.setTextExternally(res.getString("anzahl")); 

}
```

**Update 2:**

This update shows a specific example of a Swing application being used with the methods I have already provided, with a few changes now that I see your base GUI code. I would suggest building off from these files if you need a direct example to work up from:

Your GUI_Lager class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GUI_Lager extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel textPB1;


    public GUI_Lager() {
        //no need for constructor, so it can be null
    }

    public void showGUI() {
        //let's make the GUI here
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        //-----------------your code
        //let's give it dummy text at first to ensure we can change it
        textPB1 = new JLabel("Dummy Text");
        textPB1.setBounds(200, 10, 400, 25);
        textPB1.setVisible(true);
        add(textPB1);
        //-----------------your code
    }

    public void setTextExternally(String text) {
        //alters the text of class variable/label textPB1
        textPB1.setText(text);
    }


}
```

And then the Count class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI_Lager gui = new GUI_Lager();
        gui.showGUI();      //you must show the GUI first

        //now we change the value, it will be done using your SQL selection from before
        gui.setTextExternally("Awesome, it works!");    

        //launch Count.java and the Swing application will have a
        // single label that says "Awesome, it works!"
        //...change your data as needed based on your specific implementation

        //but let's also show how to change it using console input
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What do you want to change the text label to?");
        String text = scan.nextLine().trim();
        gui.setTextExternally(text);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your fast help! But the textPB1 is in the Main Class (GUI) not in the Minor Class.

Comment: In the Main GUI class create a method and call that from the Minor class which accomplishes the same functionality. Check my update, all you need to do is pass the database data around your classes

Comment: Well ok... so it do not work Jet..I put "textPB1 = new JLabel(res.getString("anzahl"));" into my SQL querry under the while statement. But i dont know how to show the value in the GUI now?

Comment: I start the GUI first. And on the first window the value should be displayed from the beginning.

Comment: Then simple, before you load the GUI, run the code I have provided and it should update prior to being launched...if it does not can you provide full GUI code so I can see where the issue is?

Comment: I update the Code on the top. The  GUI is very big so i put out the important parts. Do you find the misstake?

Comment: Hmm...you seem to have the setup incorrect, I am making a few changes and will post a second update in a bit. It will not use your database because I do not have access to it, but it will do what you are asking, give me a little bit

Comment: Check my update, it works as you are expecting...just plug in the database data instead of my hard coded Strings. **I would also suggest you start looking up JavaFX for future GUIs if you can. The last I heard, Swing may be becoming depreciated sometime soon, plus I find layouts using FX are much easier to put together, it seems much more "free"**

Comment: Did this not work for you? Let me know if you need a different idea worked out.